# How to get a string value only when 'ok' button is clicked of text entry dialog?

Tags: android, click, onclick

i have made a function taketext() which returns a string value of entered text in a text entry dialogbox. Below is the code (which is obviously incorrect). I want this to return the string only when 'ok' button is clicked. If the 'if' is removed, then it always returns null. This takeText() method is called by another method.

```
private String takeText() {
    String text = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View addView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_tag, null);
    final DialogWrapper wrapper = new DialogWrapper(addView);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Enter Text")
            .setView(addView)
            .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // processAdd(wrapper);
                    // text = wrapper.getData();
                    okBClicked = true;

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                            // ignore, just dismiss
                        }
                    }).show();
    if (okBClicked)
        return wrapper.getData();
    else
    //???
}
```

Comment: why you made such a lengthy method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont make your method to return string. Code it to show popup for entering string. Later, you have to get reference to your EditText defined in R.layout.text_tag and fetch its value in PositiveButton's click event. for example:

```
String text = null;

private void popToTakeText() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View addView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_tag, null);

    EditText txtBox = addView.findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text_box);

    final DialogWrapper wrapper = new DialogWrapper(addView);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Enter Text")
            .setView(addView)
            .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // processAdd(wrapper);
                    // text = wrapper.getData();
                    okBClicked = true;
                    text = txtBox.getText();

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                            // ignore, just dismiss
                        }
                    }).show();

}
```

Comment: well, the solution was close to this. actually i had to write this value of text onto database using method, say, writetoDB(String s). So instead of doing writetoDB(takeText()), with some little modifications, i first called void takeText() and then in onClick method, i called writetoDB(text). thats it.